# Hosting svelte-kit on aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, svelte, sveltekit, aws-amplify

I’ve been trying to deploy my svelte-kit project to aws amplify but whenever I do, despite the build and deploy stages being successful, the page returns a 404 error. I’ve changed the build settings to '/build' which is the output directory I've specified, and I'm using svelte-js/adapter-node but have tried a few other adapters. When I download the build artifacts from aws the build is the exact same as what is produced locally (by npm run build).

[Build Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YwEy.png)

Amplify Domain returns: "No web page was found for the web address:"

I've attatched an image of the end of the amplify build, which includes the warning 'no index.html found' as svelte-kit doesn't seem to produce an index.html. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Anyway to deploy a dynamic svelte project to amplify is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I flipped over to using adapter-static (and svelte kit) and it seems to work for me.